# python - check if condition is true for all i

Tags: python

I would like to see if there is a Python equivalent to the mathematical concept of "for all" (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), for example to check if some condition is True for all instances being evaluated.

**For example**

Assuming:

```
word1 = 'pizza' 
word2 = 'piza'
```

I would like to check if each letter in 'piza' is in 'pizza', and conversely if each letter in 'pizza' is in 'piza'.

Is there a way of achieving this with something such as a `for loop`?

e.g. `for letter in word1:`

Comment: Check out [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: `all(letter in word1 for letter in word2)`

Comment: Your particular example can be implemented as `set(word1) == set(word2)`

Answer (score 1):

In the example problem you provided I'd just use `set` to check if a string contains each letter from another string:

```
print set('pizza') == set('piza') # True, both strings have same set of letters
print set('pia') <= set('pizza') # True, 'pizza' contains all letters found in 'pia'
print set('pizza') <= set('pia') # False, 'pia' doesn't contain all letters found in 'pizza'
```

In a general case I'd use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a generator**

We can use a generator coupled with Python's [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to achieve this easily.

```
word1 = 'piza'
word2 = 'pizza'

print(all(letter in word1 for letter in word2))
print(all(letter in word2 for letter in word1))
```

**Or Expanded**

Expanding the one-liner makes it a little bit easier to see what is going on. The function continues until it has gone through all of the letters in `word1` and checked to see if they are in `word2`. If the function finishes the `for loop`, it means that all of the letters in `word1` are in `word2`, so it returns `True`. If one letter of `word1` is not in `word2`, it returns `False`.

```
word1 = 'pizza'
word2 = 'piza'

def if_letters_in(word1, word2):
    for letter in word1:
        if letter not in word2:
            return False
    return True

print(if_letters_in(word1, word2))
print(if_letters_in(word2, word1))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Non matching elements will be added to the generator making it non empty, so the condition fails

```
a="pizza"
b="izap"    
if not { x for x in b if not x in a } :
    #your code here
```